# Can we set manually the date of a git commit (even back in time)

Tags: git

I'd like to use git as a history book 
therefore to have each important date in history as a commit 
I would have to set or change the commit date manuelly
is this possible ?

Comment: Perhaps you should add the dates as tags, or in the subject lines of your commits. In any case, git isn't very suited to interpolate new commits between the existing ones, perhaps just a file with records tagged by the date (and kept sorted) is a better match?